# Mongo: cross referencing values in other objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks like the ff:

```
{
"word":"approve",
"related" : [
    {
        "relationshipType" : "cross-reference",
        "words" : [
            "note"
        ]
    },
    {
        "relationshipType" : "synonym",
        "words" : [
            "demonstrate",
            "ratify",
        ]
    }
],
},
{
"word": "note",
"related" : [
    {
        "relationshipType" : "synonym",
        "words" : [
            "butt",
            "need",
        ],
    },
    {
        "relationshipType" : "hypernym",
        "words" : [
            "air",
            "tone",
        ]
    },
    {
        "relationshipType" : "cross-reference",
        "words" : [
            "sign",
            "letter",
            "distinction",
            "notice",
        ]
    },
],

}
```

I want to group/categorize all the objects which have a word in another object, be it

1. the name (as the cross-reference field of 'approve', has note. searches for the word 'note'. 
   or
2. the word is in another object's related words. like having a synonym of 'ratify' under 'approve' then looking for other objects that have have 'ratify' in any field of their related words.

Then save these to a new collection called categories.
result should Be:

```
{
 "category": 1,
 "words":["approve","note"],
}
```

...and the value of the word field for all the linked objects in the words array.

Any way how to do this.. i'm thinking about some sort of recursion in checking links but i'm not sure how to implement. another potential problem is going back to the parent layer creating an infinite loop of sorts.

and is it possible through map reduce?

EDIT: clarity.

Comment: That isn't coming across as clear as you might think. You would do well to actually show what result you want based on the sample documents yo have.

Comment: oh ok, sorry. gimme a sec

Comment: While the edit does provide better data it still does not address what was asked in that you are not showing a sample of what the data should look like at the end. So if these are two documents, what do you expect your "merged" result to look like?